# Как распарсить повторяющиеся данные в итерабельную структуру(лист, словарь)?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

От сервера мне приходят ответы подобного вида (рандомно):

```
    ubs:89564: current: oil_change:""
    client:2629: dist:<empty>
    client:2629: spec modes:DW
    client:2629: timer:2017.01.04 17:38:46
    client:2629: pack:391, gov_num:213042, start:2016.12.02 02:05:25, end:2016.12.09 02:05:25
    client:2629: pack:392, gov_num:213043, start:2016.12.02 02:05:25, end:2016.12.12 02:05:25
    client:2629: pack:230, gov_num:211624, start:2016.11.22 14:30:37, end:2999.12.31 00:00:01
subs:7090: stnd:1, sbst:active, rtst:0
```

или

```
client:7090: queue:118,117
client:7090: discount:LU,MAX
client:7090: charge period:2017.01.05 14:42:58/2017.01.06 14:42:58, qad:155
client:7090: charge period:2017.01.05 14:42:16/2017.01.06 14:42:16, pack:61:214166
client:7090: timer:2017.02.04 14:42:22
client:7090: rtpl:30, rtpl join:2017.01.05 14:42:22, zone:2, doc:"250026529", start:2016.01.05 14:42:22, end:2999.12.31 00:00:01, current
```

Вопрос в чём, мне необходимо определить, что в ответе присутствует строка такого формата `"client:2629: pack:392, gov_num:213043, start:2016.12.02 02:05:25, end:2016.12.12 02:05:25"`. Т.е. если прилетел ответ 2 формата, то мы не парсим его совсем. И далее мне необходимо в список закинуть значения pack, gov_num, start, end. Я в данный момент вроде составил регулярку типа `"?<=pack:)-?\d+\.?\d*"` и т.д. чтобы получать эти данные по-отдельности, но вот как для каждого нового клиента заводить новый лист. 
т.е. результат, в случае получение первого ответа, которого я добиваюсь примерно такой (можно в листе, можно в словаре, не принципиально):

```
[(391, 213042, 2016.12.02 02:05:25, 2016.12.09 02:05:25),
 (392, 213043, 2016.12.02 02:05:25, 2016.12.12 02:05:25),
 (230, 211624, 2016.11.22 14:30:37, 2999.12.31 00:00:01)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
import re

In [182]: print(s)

    ubs:89564: current: oil_change:""
    client:2629: dist:<empty>
    client:2629: spec modes:DW
    client:2629: timer:2017.01.04 17:38:46
    client:2629: pack:391, gov_num:213042, start:2016.12.02 02:05:25, end:2016.12.09 02:05:25
    client:2629: pack:392, gov_num:213043, start:2016.12.02 02:05:25, end:2016.12.12 02:05:25
    client:2629: pack:230, gov_num:211624, start:2016.11.22 14:30:37, end:2999.12.31 00:00:01
subs:7090: stnd:1, sbst:active, rtst:0

In [183]: re.findall(r'\s+pack:(\d+),\s*gov_num:(\d+),\s*start:([^\,\n\r]*),\s*end:([^\,\n\r]*)', s)
Out[183]:
[('391', '213042', '2016.12.02 02:05:25', '2016.12.09 02:05:25'),
 ('392', '213043', '2016.12.02 02:05:25', '2016.12.12 02:05:25'),
 ('230', '211624', '2016.11.22 14:30:37', '2999.12.31 00:00:01')]

In [184]: print(s2)

client:7090: queue:118,117
client:7090: discount:LU,MAX
client:7090: charge period:2017.01.05 14:42:58/2017.01.06 14:42:58, qad:155
client:7090: charge period:2017.01.05 14:42:16/2017.01.06 14:42:16, pack:61:214166
client:7090: timer:2017.02.04 14:42:22
client:7090: rtpl:30, rtpl join:2017.01.05 14:42:22, zone:2, doc:"250026529", start:2016.01.05 14:42:22, end:2999.12.31 00:00:01, current

In [185]: re.findall(r'\s+pack:(\d+),\s*gov_num:(\d+),\s*start:([^\,\n\r]*),\s*end:([^\,\n\r]*)', s2)
Out[185]: []
```